# Migrate SQLite database to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, migration

After using SQLite for development and beta-testing for a home-project I want to migrate the DB to Microsoft SQL Server to get better performance. Is there any free/cheap utils that will do this?

So far I have found [DBConvert](http://dbconvert.com/convert-sqlite-to-mssql-pro.php) that looks like a good product, are there others?

Comment: @Espo: I recommend using "SQL Server" instead of "MSSQL", since there is no product by that name, and since it can be confused with "MySql"

Comment: Don't assume you'll get better performance.  You might get worse.  You might get a LOT worse.  Depends on your data and usage pattern.  (And you might bet better performance too...)

Comment: @John Saunders, I think MSSQL is much clearer than SQL Server.  SQL Server is a generic name and can be used to refer to any SQL-supporting and server-based database.  There are other products that use SQL Server as a part of their name  even.  Sybase's own documentation uses the term "Sybase SQL Server".

Comment: @Sam: I disagree. There is an actual product named "Microsoft SQL Server". There is not product named "MSSQL". If you like, you can call it "Microsoft SQL Server", but I've never seen confusion over whether "SQL Server" might not have meant "Sybase SQL Server". On the other hand, I have several times seen confusion over whether "MSSQL" meant "MySQL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few choices here:
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools