# How to read tables from SQLIte and store it in Microsoft SQL Server in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sqlite

I have a requirement to read SQLite Database and store it in SQL server.
is there any API or library available in .NET which is used to read Database tables from SQLite and store it in SQL Server?

Comment: This has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361678/migrate-sqlite-database-to-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361678/migrate-sqlite-database-to-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Generate the scrip of you database from SQLlite and same script run on SQL server Query analyzer  .. it may be helpful for you

[Look this Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH82x.png)